# What join to use

Tags: php, join, pdo, authentication

I have two tables, one for registered users and one to store votes.
We are logging in with registrants.id and registrants.zipcode. Once they vote their votes are inserted into the votes table, along with their Registration ID.

Im trying to right a select statement that returns a record that will select all the records for Matched ID and Zipcode, but the ID is not in the Votes.voter column. i have tried all kinds of variations of all the joins i can think of. is it something simple i am missing.

```html
SELECT * FROM registrants 
LEFT JOIN votes on registrants.id = votes.voter 
WHERE registrants.id = 1 AND registrants.zipcode = 46706 and votes.voter <> 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a `not exists` query:

```
select * from registrants
where registrants.zipcode = '46706'
and not exists (select 1 from votes where registrants.id = votes.voter)
```

Comment: That works to get a result. But I want Where registrants.id and registrants.zipcode match. But the registrants.id isn’t already listed in votes.voter

Comment: I see. In that case use `votes.voter is null` or `not exists` as above.

Comment: This absolutely was the the solution to my problem! for the most part. had to workshop it but the NOT EXISTS was the answer to my problem.